# Open part of Github repository as IntelliJ project

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I have large Github repository with individual projects uploaded as subdirectories. Those subdirectories are IntelliJ IDEA projects that I want to work on, but the problem is that I can only clone the whole repository. Instead, I want to clone whole repository, open individual subdirectories as IntelliJ projects and make commits visible to entire repository. Can it be done, or do I have to destroy the repository, create directory and make every project a separate repository in subdirectories?

I have something like:

```
- main_directory (repository):
  - lab1 (first project)
  - lab2 (second project)
```

I want to clone whole repository and commit to entire repository, but edit individual projects with IntelliJ. It can be done with Github Desktop, but I want to do it from IntelliJ.

Comment: If the projects are stored in the subdirectories, what's the problem opening just one project from `lab1` in IntelliJ IDEA? Version Control mapping can point to an upper directory (https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-version-control.html#associate_directory_with_VCS).

Comment: Yeah, you're right! I feel kinda stupid right now... I was sure that it would be only be VCS for a subdirectory, for some reason. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can map any directory to the version control in IntelliJ IDEA [VCS Settings](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/enabling-version-control.html#associate_directory_with_VCS).

So you can open any project like `lab1` and associate `main_directory` with the version control.